# How to get liability insurance for an electric kick scooter in California?

Tags: insurance, california, liability

I just purchased a Segway Ninebot ES4 electric kick scooter.

I'm from the Netherlands but live in the United States (California).

I have a global liability insurance but it excludes motorized vehicles, including electric kick scooters.

Is it possible to insure for personal liability specifically for claims made due to riding this electric kick scooter in California?

Answer (score 4):

Most people in the United States have liability insurance through their automobile policy and their homeowners policy. If they don't own a home, they should have renters insurance.

If these types of policies don't cover all the liability situations then those same insurance companies usually offer some sort of umbrella policy.  That is where I would start if there was a liability coverage gap that needs to be addressed.

Don't contact the website or the toll-free number, talk to a local agent. They should be able to give you options. There may also be savings if you get the liability coverage from a company that you already have a policy from.

Comment: As a non-citizen I don't have any domestic insurances yet (don't have a car or a home either). I'll look for a local agent.

Comment: Renters insurance is inexpensive. It will protect your stuff where you live.

Comment: I'm interested in liability insurance. E.g. if I accidentally hit someone with my electric kick scooter, and this person sues me for damages resulting from a handicap.

Comment: Renters Insurance can also come with a liability coverage. Explain what you want to the local agent.

Comment: A lot of insurance companies offer ATV and other non car or sport related vehicle insurances, at the least I know of Liberty Mutual, AllState, GEICO (in some cases). A wide variety of companies who offers car insurance will offer liability insurance for non car vehicles. You can check this online without any need for an agent or complex phone calls for most companies. (I have never spoken to any kind of agent and have several relatively weird insurances)

Answer (score 2):

There are two major forms of liability coverage you need to know about: property damage liability and bodily injury liability. Property damage liability will help you cover the cost of repairing a third-party’s property (such as a fence or sled) in the event that you damage it while operating your scooter. Bodily injury liability offers coverage for the medical treatment that a third-party might require after an accident that you caused.

The short answer is that it will be difficult to purchase coverage for what you want because the type of vehicle you have falls into the same category as snowmobiles and ATVs (anything that is not registered with the government and therefore does not have a license plate) - most homeowners or renters policies exclude liability associated with these and it's difficult to get them to add it on to (endorse in the insurance world) the policy; the reason behind this is that the downside is very high for the insurance company and the premium is very low.